# pig date conversion from M/dd/YYYY to YYYY-MM-dd

Tags: date, apache-pig

I want to compare two dates in `1/22/2016` and `2016-02-13` format I am unable to figure out pig function to write this.

Do I need to write a UDF for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dump A;
1/22/2016

B = foreach A generate ToDate($0,"M/dd/yyyy");
C = foreach B {

  year = (chararray)GetYear($0);
  month = (chararray)GetMonth($0);
  day = (chararray)GetDay($0);
  generate CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(year, '-'), CONCAT(month, '-')),day) as myDate;
}

Dump C;
(2016-1-22)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all by ToDate and compare by > < == notation. Example:

```
R = FILTER A BY ToDate(date1, 'M/d/yyyy') <= ToDate(date2, 'YYYY-mm-dd');
```